# How to interpolate a misaligned data set in PHP/MySQL for D3

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I have a EAV table where my data is

```
stageid, value,     row
1        rob        1
2        01/01/2012 1
3        2000       1
1        Ben        2
2 ......... and so on
```

I have to transpose/pivot this data into a usable format eg a three column table

The horrific looking query is

```
SELECT pearson,
Date_format(a.salesdate, '%Y-%m-01') AS       monthYear,
Count(1)
FROM  (SELECT row,
                          Group_concat(IF(stageid = 74, value, NULL)) AS 'pearson',
                          Group_concat(IF(stageid = 59, Str_to_date(value, '%d/%m/%Y'), NULL)) AS 'salesdate',
                          Group_concat(IF(stageid= 67, value, NULL))  AS 'salescount'
                   FROM   stagingdata
                   GROUP  BY row) AS a
            WHERE  a.pearson IS NOT NULL
                   AND a.pearson != ''
                   AND Year(a.salesdate) IN ( '2012', '2011' )
            GROUP  BY Trim(Lower(a.pearson)),
                      Date_format(a.salesdate, '%Y-%m')
            HAVING Count(1) > 10
    ORDER  BY pearson, a.salesdate ASC
```

I get this result

```
Person, Date,  Sales
Rob     2012-01-01 2000
Ben     2012-01-01 500
Ben     2012-03-01 300
Rob     2012-05-01 2000
```

I want to use NVD3 to create a stacked area chart, however as you can see the data in the date column is mis-aligned - I think I need to inter polate the data - but I dont know how!

so my data should look like

```
Person, Date,  Sales
Rob     2012-01-01 2000
Ben     2012-01-01 500
Ben     2012-03-01 300
Rob     2012-03-01 0
Rob     2012-05-01 2000
Rob     2012-05-01 0
```

Do I do this in my Query?? in PHP < prefriably not! as I want my 3 column chart php to json creator to be as generic as possible - or can you do this in NVD3 or D3

Comment: for all that's good and pure, why the HECK are you store the dates in non-native formats? `Date_format(Str_to_date(a.salesdate, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m')` is just plain ... silly. store them as native date times and eliminate the str_to_date overhead. consider how much nicer `YEAR(a.salesdate) IN (2011,2012)` is v.s. your monstrosity.

Comment: as mentioned at the top of the question I have an EAV http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model structure - so the value column store multiple data types - hence why date is not stored as date - I would love to use YEAR(a.salesdate)

Comment: Point taken @MarcB, I have made the query simpler. Thanks